# JSON convert Ignore Empty Object C#

Tags: object

I try to ignore an empty object on my Json

this is my Json :
**{
"custNmae": "test n test p",
"firstName": "test n",
"lastName": "test p",
"updateDate": "2018-12-28T16:25:25Z",
"tutor": {}
}**

Does any one have a idea how to resolve this ?

Please let me know !!!!

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: I need to omit tutor: {} from my Json when it's empty no need to send it instead of this  { "custNmae": "test n test p", "firstName": "test n", "lastName": "test p", "updateDate": "2018-12-28T16:25:25Z", "tutor": {} }

I wanna this  { "custNmae": "test n test p", "firstName": "test n", "lastName": "test p", "updateDate": "2018-12-28T16:25:25Z" }

Comment: here is my code :  string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerB2C, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new SkipEmptyContractResolver(),
                        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
                    });

Answer (score -1):

```
    private class CustomerB2C
    {
        public string custName = "";
        public string firstName = "";
        public string lastName = "";
        public DateTime updateDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        public Tutor tutor = null;
    }

    private class Tutor
    {
        public string tutorName = "";
    }

    private static void test()
    {
        CustomerB2C customerB2C = new CustomerB2C();
        customerB2C.custName = "Mike Smith";
        customerB2C.firstName = "Mike";
        customerB2C.lastName = "Smith";
        customerB2C.updateDate = DateTime.Now;
        customerB2C.tutor = null; //is already null, setting to null here for demonstration purposes
        string json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerB2C);
        string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerB2C, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: It doesn't work for me still the empty  object appeared in json format

Comment: I revised my answer and included a screenshot.  The code string json1 is including the null tutor object and json2 is omitting the null tutor object.  Does this help?  If not, then I don't understand your question.